# How should common references be passed around in an assembly?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, singleton, static-classes

I am trying to get rid off static classes, static helper methods and singleton classes in my code base. Currently, they are pretty much spread over the whole code, especially so for the utility classes and the logging library. This is mainly due to the need for mocking ability as well as object-oriented design and development concerns, e.g. extensibility. I might also need to introduce some form of dependency injection in the future and would like to leave an open door for that.

Basically, the problem I have encountered is about the method of passing the commonly used references around. These are objects that are used by almost every class in the code base, such as the logging interface, the utility (helper) class interface and maybe an instance of a class that holds an internal common state for the assembly which most classes relate to.

There are two options, as far as I'm aware. One is to define a class (or an interface) that stores the common references, a context if you will, and pass the context to each object that is created. The other option is to pass each common reference to almost every class as a separate parameter which  would increase the number of parameters of the class constructors.

Which one of these methods is better, what are the pros and cons of each, and is there a better method for this task?

Comment: Research [Dependency Injection](https://www.google.com/search?q=dependency+injection+.net).  It's way too broad a topic to be answered in this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally go with the context object approach, and pass the context object either to an object's constructor, or to a method -- depending on which one makes the most sense.

The context object pattern can take a few forms.

You can define an interface that has exactly the members you need, or you can generate a sort of container class.  For example, when writing loosely-coupled components, I tend to have each component I implement have a matching interface, so that it can be reimplemented if desired.  Then I register the objects on a "manager" object, something like this:

```
public interface IServiceManager
{
    public T GetService<T>();
    public T RequireService<T>();
    public void RegisterService<T>(T service);
    public void UnregisterService<T>(T service);
}
```

Behind the scenes there is a map from type to object, which allows me to extremely quickly assemble a large set of diverse components into a working whole.  Each component asks for the others by interface, and the manager object is what glues them together.  (If you correctly author your components, you can even swap out one service for another while the process is running!)

One would register a service something along these lines:

```
class FooService : IFooService { }

// During process start-up:
serviceManager.RegisterService<IFooService>(new FooService());
```

There is more overhead with this approach than with the flat-interface approach due to the dictionary lookup, but it has allowed me to build very sophisticated systems that can be easily redeployed with different service implementations.  (And, as is usual, any bottlenecks I encounter are never in looking up a service object from a dictionary, but somewhere else such as the database.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this is exactly the type of feedback I'm looking forward to. As far as I know this kind of a factory, or service provider approach is used in the TFS 2012 API. Is it meaningful in this approach to register more than one concrete implementation for the same interface? If so, what would that mean and how would the manager possible resolve the dependency?

Comment: @exc It can be depending on the context.  I have written [such an implementation](https://github.com/cdhowie/Cdh.Toolkit/blob/master/Cdh.Toolkit.Services/ServiceManager.cs) that I use in several projects with success.  It resolves the ambiguity by throwing an exception if you asked for exactly one implementation, but will return all implementations if you ask it for more than one.  Other algorithms are possible of course -- go with whichever one solves your problem the best.

Comment: This isn't really a _context_ pattern - it's a _Service Locater_ pattern

Comment: @DStanley I consider the service locater pattern to be a particular specialization of the context pattern.  The primary difference, AFAICT, is that a context object has first-class properties for each bit of data you need to share, while a service locator object allows arbitrary registration of new objects.  I don't consider that difference terribly significant, at least not in this particular language.

Comment: @cdhowie I'll take a look at the code, thank you. I think this reduces the problem to passing the service manager reference around. Do you pass the service manager reference to class constructors where one class needs a service of another?

Comment: @cdhowie I consider the context pattern as a class with a pre-defined set of "services" exposed as properties of a class (e.g. `HttpContext` has properties for `Request`, `Response`, `Error`, `Session`, etc.)  I suppose you could think of the Service Locator as a "untyped" context - but I wouldn't call it a "specialized" context. (maybe "genericised"?)

Comment: @exc Yes.  If the service is only needed for a short duration in one particular method, then I pass the manager object to that method instead of the constructor, but it's more frequent that I pass it to the constructor.

Comment: @DStanley Your definition of context pattern agrees with mine then; perhaps I just didn't explain it clearly enough.  Perhaps specialized was the wrong word, yes -- "genericized context" seems as good a description as any.

Comment: I have come across [this article](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/10/27/pass-around-ginormous-context-objects/), which seems to be related. It seems that the service locator, or service manager pattern that you propose does not suffer from some of the drawbacks of the context pattern. When you pass a complex context to a class, the class is now dependant on the whole context even if it is not wholly used. This is not the case for the service locator pattern since the service manager does not make any promises about which services it can provide.

Comment: @exc Indeed, and it may provide services that the consuming code is not even aware of.  One of my favorite things about JavaScript it that it's *so damn easy* to ask if the browser supports something by just checking whether or not it's there.  I like compile-time checks, but there are cases where it works against you, and fleshing out a big system with lots of interdependent components is one of them, I think.  The "service locator" pattern provides a lot of that flexibility that I often lament is missing from C#.

Comment: Be very aware that while using a Service Locator is "easy" - it often hides bugs that certainly won't show up at compile time, and very often won't show up until _deployment_ if not configured properly.  Just fair warning...

Comment: @DStanley Of course.  Sacrificing compile-time safety is a conscious decision, and I can't say that I've found no bugs in my use of this pattern, but the flexibility it gives me more than makes up for the bit of extra debugging.

Comment: @DStanley Its strength is its weakness, in a sense, which is the fact the dependencies are not revealed through the class interface and are rather hidden. This can be either desired or to be avoided depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to get varied opinions, but *generally* passing a separate parameter to the constructor for each dependency is preferred for a few reasons:

- It clearly defines the actual dependencies for a class - with a "context" you don't know which parts of the context are used without digging into the code.
- Generally having a lot of parameters to a constructor is a design smell, so using constructor injection helps you sniff out design flaws.
- When testing you can mock out individual dependencies versus having to mock an entire context

Comment: I agree with your remarks, though, on the other hand, passing a reference to a logging class or a utility class to almost every little object that I create really messes up the code I think. I'm not sure if there is a clean solution to this. Some would probably claim it is better to leave such classes as static classes or singletons but it has its own set of problems.

Comment: A couple of ways to address that are 1) having a base class that holds the logger, 2) make the logger an "optional" dependency by using Setter Injection, and 3) do the logging at a higher level and "bubble up" logging through events.  One big drawback to static objects/singletons is it makes unit testing difficult because you can't stub/mock a singleton.

Comment: I definitely agree on the big drawback about static objects and singletons. As for 1), a base class is too precious, especially in languages without multiple inheritance as such I don't think I want to use inheritance just to pass the reference to the logger around. But this can definitely be useful for natural class hierarchies. I have thought about 2) before and I think people that use the code will forget to set the logger reference after object creation and then the logging would silently fail when you need it. 3) is interesting and definitely has its own place where it would be useful.

Comment: To answer the heart of your question - If every little class _needs_ a logger and you don't want a static class then I don't see a way around it. There are DI frameworks (like Ninject) that take some of the "grunt" code out of the picture, but I still think you'll want to inject those dependencies in some way to improve testability.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing as a parameter to the constructor. This has great advantage for both dependency injection and unit testability ( mocking).

Comment: I think the argument is passing _one_ reference to the constructor with _several_ properties or _several_ references to the constructor.